# Add column to table with column position and unique constraints in laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Trying to add column to table in laravel5.2 without refresh and

that column should have unique constraints and can set the position of that column.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_group_law_master', function($table) {
    $table->string('group_id')->unique()->after('lm_id');
 });
}

   public function down()
   {
    Schema::table('tbl_group_law_master', function($table) {
    $table->dropColumn('group_id');
   });
}
```

This is not working

Answer (score 0):

Create a new migration file for adding new column in existing table.

New migration will look like -

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_group_law_master', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //if display_name is not added, add this column
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('tbl_group_law_master','group_id')) {
            $table->string('group_id', 20)->after('lm_id')->unique();
        }
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('tbl_group_law_master', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //if display_name is not added, add this column
        if(Schema::hasColumn('tbl_group_law_master','group_id')) {
            $table->dropColumn('group_id');
        }
    });
}
```

Then run command - 
`php artisan migrate`